# Excel and R give me different answer for first Quantile

Tags: r, excel

I have the following data set (`n = 20`).

```
35, 50, 50, 50, 60, 75, 75, 75, 80,85,85,90,90,100,100,100,100,125,125,150
```

I try to find the first quantile. I do it manually as follows:

```
(25 / 100) * 20 = 5.
```

That means, the average of the `5th` and the `6th` positions, as follows:

```
(60+75)/2 = 67.5
```

However, when I do it in excel or R, they gave me, `Q_1 = 71.25`

Could you please help me to understand the problem?

Comment: `?quantile` : quantile returns *estimates* of underlying distribution quantiles based on one or two order statistics from the supplied elements in x at probabilities in probs

Answer (score 1):

R has nine types of quantiles. Perhaps you need type 2:

```
> x = c(35, 50, 50, 50, 60, 75, 75, 75, 80,85,85,90,90,100,100,100,100,125,125,150)
> quantile(x, probs = 0.25, type = 2)
 25% 
67.5
```

Answer (score 0):

python will do the same

the reason is that the cutoff is between 60 and 75, but 75 is present 3 times, so the calculation is not `(60+75)/2=67.5` but rather `(60+75+75+75)/4=71.25`

Comment: Thanks, but how to fix it in excel?

Comment: don't know about excel, but in R you can fix it with Stephanes answer